# Comparing local and ftp files with cmp and find

Tags: linux, ftp, compare, cmp

I want to compare files in a local folder with subfolders to its counterpart on a ftp server and delete the unchanged files in my local folder. My command currently looks like this (inspired by the answer from https://superuser.com/questions/561187/diff-between-two-directories-and-keep-only-the-unchanged-ones)

```
find . -type f -exec cmp {} ftp://$FTP_USERNAME:$FTP_PASSWORD@$HOST/html/{} \; -delete
```

When comparing two local folders, the command works as expected. When using the ftp directory, the command returns `No such file or directory` for every file, because it adds `./` between the remote directory and the directory to search for. Example:

```
cmp: ftp://$FTP_USERNAME:$FTP_PASSWORD@$HOST/html/./subdirectory/index.html: No such file or directory
```

Someone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: What made you think you can use a URL as a filename on Linux?

Comment: Use `wget` or `curl` to copy the file to the local machine, then compare it.